# When i convert images to greyscale with pil it rotates them

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When i convert images to greyscale with pil it rotates them.
How do i disable this?

```
from PIL import Image
import os

path = 'spanish_pages_photos/'
pathContents = os.listdir(path)

list = []

# get file names and append to list
for i in pathContents:
    list.append(i)
    
list = sorted(list)

#loop through and change to grey scale
for i in list[2:]:
    img = Image.open(f'spanish_pages_photos/{i}').convert('L')
    img.save(f'spanish_pages_photos/{i}')
print('finished')
```

Comment: It's probably not PIL rotating the images, it's whatever you're using to view them that rotates the original based on the EXIF saved in the image when you took the picture.  And that EXIF is lost when you make a copy of the image by converting it.

Answer (score 1):

The EXIF data can contain an *"EXIF Orientation"* field. Try auto-orienting with `PIL.ImageOps.exif_transpose()`.

See [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.exif_transpose).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```py
img = Image.open(f'spanish_pages_photos/{i}').convert('L')
```

Try this:

```py
img = Image.open(f'spanish_pages_photos/{i}')
img = PIL.ImageOps.exif_transpose()
img = img.convert('L')
```