# When creating a GIF of two images using Pillow in python it is messing up Image orientation

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When I try to create a GIF using Pillow one of the two images is being rotated in random direction resulting in a gif where one image is like the original but the other one is rotated anticlockwise.

I am using it in a lambda fuction to make a GIF of two image showing the original and edited image so I need them both in the original orientation.

My Code ->

```py
import json
import boto3
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import uuid

s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
dynamodb = boto3.client("dynamodb")

def makeGIF(orig_string, after_string):
    frames = [Image.open(BytesIO(orig_string)), Image.open(BytesIO(after_string))]
    frame_one = frames[0]
    frame_one.save('/tmp/new_gif.gif', format="GIF", append_images=[frames[1]],
                save_all=True, duration=600, loop=0, optimize=False)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        s3 = event["Records"][0]['s3']
        print("S3 object reveived::",s3)
        
        if s3['object']['key'][-1] == '/': return
        splitted = s3['object']['key'].split("/")
        if len(splitted) != 3:
            print("ERROR:: Folder hierarchy is not valid!")
            return {}
        
        afterFilename = splitted[-1].replace("+", " ")
        print('Filename::', afterFilename)
        if afterFilename[0:6] not in ['after_', 'AFTER_', 'After_']:
            print('Error::', 'Filename does not starts with after_, After_ or AFTER_')
            return {}
        
        EXT = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png']
        
        origFilename = afterFilename[6:]
        origKey = f"original/{splitted[1]}/{origFilename}"
        fileWithoutExt = origFilename.split(".")[0]

        BUCKET = s3['bucket']['name']
    
        file_content_orig = None
        try:
            file_content_orig = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=origKey)["Body"].read()
        except:
            for ext in EXT:
                try:
                    print("LOOKING::", f"original/{splitted[1]}/{fileWithoutExt}{ext}")
                    file_content_orig = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=f"original/{splitted[1]}/{fileWithoutExt}{ext}")["Body"].read()
                    print("FOUND::", f"original/{splitted[1]}/{fileWithoutExt}{ext}")
                    break
                except: pass
        if file_content_orig is None:
            print('Error::', 'No original image found looked (jpg, jpeg, png)')
            return {}
        print("LOOKING::", f"after/{splitted[1]}/{afterFilename}")
        file_content_after = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=f"after/{splitted[1]}/{afterFilename}")["Body"].read()
        
        makeGIF(file_content_orig, file_content_after)
        
        gifKey = f"gif/{splitted[1]}/gif_{fileWithoutExt}.gif"
    
        with open('/tmp/new_gif.gif', 'rb') as f:
            s3_client.upload_fileobj(f, BUCKET, gifKey)
        
        itemId = uuid.uuid4().hex
        
        bucketLink = f"https://{BUCKET}.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
        print("bucketLink", bucketLink)
        item = {
            "id": {'S': itemId},
            "folder_name": {'S': splitted[1]},
            "image_name": {'S': origFilename},
            "original_link": {'S': f"{bucketLink}/{origKey}"},
            "download_link": {'S': f"{bucketLink}/{s3['object']['key']}"},
            "gif_link": {'S': f"{bucketLink}/{gifKey}"}
        }
        
        dynamodb.put_item(TableName='fototone-db-table', Item = item)
            
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps({"message": "Successfully proceessed", "filename": origFilename })
        }
    except Exception as ex:
        print("ERROR:: Some error occured", ex)
        return {}
```

Comment: You aren't showing how you create `orig_string` or `after_string`.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I updated the code.

Comment: I couldn't tell before, as I had assumed you were starting with GIF input images, but now I see that you may start off with JPEG images, so you may have an EXIF Orientation in your images that is causing PIL to rotate them. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73179120/2836621