# Why do I get the same image size (width height) with Pillow of two images even though one is portrait and the other is landscape?

Tags: image, python-imaging-library, size

I have two images:

- image_landscape.jpg (4000x3000)
- image_portrait.jpg (3000x4000)

But when a run the routine using Pillow (Image.size), which results in (width, height), the result is the same for both files.
I want to identify the orientation of each photo to rotate in order to present a photographic panel.
[landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3MCX.jpg)
[portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QEOy.jpg)

The following routine:

```
from PIL import Image
path_image_port = r'C:\Users\rolan\Downloads\image_portrait.jpg'
path_image_land = r'C:\Users\rolan\Downloads\image_landscape.jpg'
foo_port = Image.open(path_image_port)
foo_land = Image.open(path_image_land)
print(foo_port.size)
print(foo_land.size)
```

The result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8uUV.jpg)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73179120/2836621